# How to integrate iOS Apollo SDK 1.x Version using cocoapods?

Tags: ios, graphql, cocoapods, apollo-client, apollo-ios

I'm trying to integrate Apollo SDK version 1.x using cocoapods.

I have added

**pod "Apollo"**

in podfile and successfully downloaded

**Apollo (1.0.7) version.**

My question is how to add(path/directory) schema.graphqls and queries, how to generate query classes(ex : myquery.swift) for my queries.

Using SPM, I have done above process successfully using below commands

- ./apollo-ios-cli init --schema-name GraphQLAPI --module-type
  swiftPackageManager
- ./apollo-ios-cli generate

Do we have any commands like above, when we use cocoapods?

Can any one help.

Thanks in advance